# I want to update grade rows at once ...when the instructor wants to edit the grade for the rows fetched by students who did a particular assessment

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="update_grade.php">
<?php 
  $AssNo=$_GET['ass-number'];

  $i=0;

  //connect to database

  include ("connect.php");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT date, firstname, lastname, ass_type, ass_no, mark
      FROM users u, assessments a, stdass s 
      WHERE u.username = s.username AND s.ass_id = a.ass_id ) AS yusuf 
    WHERE ass_no ='$AssNo' ";

  $query1 = "SELECT * from assessments WHERE ass_no ='$AssNo'";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
  $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

  echo'<table width="625" border="1" align="right">';
  echo" <tr>";
  echo' <td width="107">Submitted-date</td>';
  echo'  <td width="86">Firstname</td>';
  echo'<td width="81">Lastname</td>';
  echo'<td width="79">Ass-type</td>';
  echo' <td width="68">Ass-no</td>';
  echo'  <td width="79">Grading</td>';
  echo"</tr>";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo"$row[date]";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo"$row[firstname]";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo"$row[lastname]";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo"$row[ass_type]";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo'<input name="ass_no" type="text" id="ass_no"value ="'.
      $row['ass_no'].'" size="2" maxlength="10" readonly/>';
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo'<input name="grade[$i]" type="text" id="grade"value ="'.
      $row['mark'].'" size="5" maxlength="10" />';
    echo"</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo'<input name="ass_id[$i]" type="hidden" id="ass_id" value="'.
    $row1['ass_id'].'" />';
?>
</table>

// this is to update it

<?php
  include ("Scripts/connect.php");

  $count = count($_POST['grade']);
  $i = 0; 
  while ($i < $count) {
    $ass_id = $_POST['ass_id'][$i];
    $grade = $_POST['grade'][$i];
    $query = "UPDATE assessments a,stdass s SET mark='$grade' 
      WHERE ass_id = '$ass_id'  ";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    if($result){ echo " UPDATED !!"; }
    ++$i;
  }
  // echo "<script> window.close(); </script>";
?>
```

Comment: What... ? You will need to provide more details.

Comment: You want to update in a loop. you did not say what is happening now! echo $ass_id and $grade. is the values coming properly .then echo query and see whats happening

Comment: #1 This is a very hack prone way of coding... Assuming you are not sanatizing the POST vars somewhere else in your script, you are vulnerable to sql injection. #2 i think you are trying to use a join in your query but do not know how. #3 you might want to consider using a for loop instead of that hacked up while loop.

Comment: echo "$ass_id";
echo "$grade"; Not showing output because of the array ..... basically i want update rows looping the grade text field and id for each rows

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE 
    assessments a, stdass s SET a.mark='$grade', s.mark='$grade' 
    WHERE a.ass_id = s.ass_id AND a.ass_id='$ass_id'";
```

Comment: i am not getting any value for $grade and $mark    .....saying  Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: It looks like you're not incrementing the value of $i in your while loop outputting each table row.

Comment: @Lake What an ass variable :-) please give proper names. Check that is a POST variable or GET . or try $_REQUEST

Comment: still the same ... echo "$ass_id";
echo "$grade"; is not showing output because of the [] or so

Comment: All i want the code to do is to update the grade fields by looping through the rows identifying them by id

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="update assessments a,stdass s set a.mark='$grade', s.mark='$grade' where a.ass_id = '$ass_id', s.ass_id = '$ass_id'  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Lake,

I'm not sure what your problem is or what you want to do that doesn't happen now, however...

**You have a gaping SQL-injection hole in your code.**
Change this code

```
$AssNo=$_GET['ass-number'];
....

$ass_id = $_POST['ass_id'][$i];
$grade = $_POST['grade'][$i];
$query = "UPDATE assessments a,stdass s SET mark='$grade' 
  WHERE ass_id = '$ass_id'  ";
```

Into this to fix it.

```
$AssNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ass-number']);
.....

$ass_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ass_id'][$i]);
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['grade'][$i]);
$query = "UPDATE assessments a,stdass s SET mark='$grade' 
  WHERE ass_id = '$ass_id'  ";
```

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
For more info on this issue.

Comment: Thank you ... I want the code to update many rows at a time thats the code